# Genus of fattened knots and links

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, knot-theory

Imagine you take a knot or link, and "fatten" it as much as possible, so that the surface
is snug against itself at several places.  Then "fuse" it into a solid object.
What I have in mind is something like this:

 
[image: Fattened Knots and Links]

The linked tori at the left ([image from an MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70888/)) fuse to an object of genus 0.
The ideal trefoil (center, [image from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ropelength)) I want to say has genus 1 when
maximally fattened and fused.  The knot $6_2$ to the right ([image from Jason Cantarella's site](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/movs/))
has, I think, genus 4 or 5, if fully fattened (more than shown).
I would want to say the unknot fattens to genus 1, never entirely closing.
I have two questions:

> **Q1**. Can this notion of fused, fattened knots be formalized consistently?  It seems that fusing should occur where surface curvatures match, whereas, say,
>   at the center of the ideal trefoil, the curvatures are opposed.
>
> **Q2**. Is there a measure on knots that corresponds, or yields this fattened genus?

This is a blue-sky exploratory well, so to speak.

Comment: Beautiful pictures, as always! I wonder though if this might depend on the embedding? For example, an unknot that is simply a circle will thicken to a genus 1 solid object (using your convention), but I don't see immediately that this will be true of any unknot.

Comment: @Zev: Yes, you are right, this depends quite on the embedding.  Good point!

Comment: Maybe it is possible to achieve a non-trivial minimum for the fat genus of any embedding of a certain knot

Comment: @James: That's what I'm hoping!